# Manjaro - how to set in routing table that addresses to internet come out by specific IP?

Tags: networking, configuration, networkmanager, vpn, ifconfig

I have a connection via VPN with my work. I know that internet connection (for example to 8.8.8.8) goes through my work network (only when I am connected to VPN).

How to configure ip tables to force that connections to internet (for example 8.8.8.8) avoid work network ?

Using @Julie help in comments I did managed to discover some options:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpJ5R.png]

Nevertheless, after checking 'Use this connection only for resources...' I can't ping machines in VPN network.

Can you tell me how should I deal with it ?   I guess that I should click 'Add' and set:
Address = address of some machine in VPN
Netmask = I can get it from ifconfig (in VPN interface)
Gateway - as in case of netmask
Metri - I have no idea ?

Am I right ?

Comment: There are many ways to do it.  The best IMO is to set up your VPN client not to use that connection as the default route and only use it for the VPN's network.

Comment: How to do it ? I am using NetworkManager (SSTP)

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, it should be in the connection's IPv4 Settings, Routes where you'd find a 'Use this connection only for resources on its network'.

Comment: @JuliePelletier  I have a problem still. When I check this option I can't get ping machines in VPN network. I have seen list to add address IP (in the same place as 'Use this connection only for resources on its network'. Can you tell what IP I should add to this list ?

Comment: You probably just need to specify the CIDR of what you want to pass through the VPN such as 10.2.0.0/24 or whatever your network topology is.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I edited and clarify where I got stuck.

Comment: We're still missing the important part.  What adresses are you trying to reach that you can't?  I'm a bit surprised that `Use this connection only for resources on its network` doesn't solve the problem by itself but it depends on your network topology.

Comment: I am trying to ping machine from VPN network (machine in work). When it comes to topology - I don't know what is it, but I can check it if you tell me how.

Comment: If you put the IP address of the machine you're trying to ping in the list, does it work for that one?  Use the VPN server's internal IP as the gateway.  You can probably find it in `ip route show dev tun0`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier when I set it then I can't connect to the VPN on the whole.

Comment: You will obviously have to contact your network administrator since this is beyond your reach.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that `Use this connection only for resources on its network` works on the current Manjaro distro. It removes the default route via the VPN network gateway.

Only the VPN traffic goes through the VPN and the rest goes through your default public Internet gateway.